# Как сделать так, чтобы сериализатор Django принимал значения вида key[value]

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Допустим мне на POST запрос приходит json вида `{"data[value]": 10}` и у меня есть сериализатор вида:

```py
class SomeSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    value = IntegerField(...)
```

Как мне сделать так, чтобы сериалайзер смог принять данные из жсона и сохранить их в поле value?
сделать что-то типа

```py
data[value] = IntegerField(...)
```

django не даст